# Enlarge image on hover and add spotlight text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having difficulty finding a tutorial on enlarging an image on mouse hover, then shading the enlarged image dark so I can put some text over it.

This example does almost everything except make the image larger:
http://jsfiddle.net/balupton/FZG3v/

CSS:

```
.ih { position:relative; }
.ih, .ih-image, .ih-info { display:block;width:330px;height:220px; }
.ih-image, .ih-info { z-index:500;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0; }
.ih-info { z-index:501;background:black;color:white; }
```

HTML:

```
<img class="ih-image" src="http://designsnack.com/screenshots/image.php width=330&amp;height=220&amp;cropratio=330:220&amp;image=/screenshots/8264948088.jpg"/>
     <div class="ih-info">
         Your overlay content
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
$('.ih').hover(
    // Over
    function(){
        var $ih = $(this);
        $ih.find('.ih-info').stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0.8}, 400);
    },
    // Out
    function(){
        var $ih = $(this);
        $ih.find('.ih-info').stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0}, 400);
    }
).find('.ih-info').css('opacity',0);
});
```

It's my first question, apologies if I am not clear or am missing some information.

Many thanks for any help!

EDIT: Thanks ghost! My end goal is to enlarge the image from the center as ultimately there will be 4 images in a 4X2 configuration.

Comment: You seem to have the shading working, try CSS3 transform `scale` for the enlargement effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this many ways using jQuery, one of them is to use `animate()` method to smoothly change image size: http://jsfiddle.net/FZG3v/44/

Comment: Thanks ghost!  Almost exactly perfect!  Just trying to work out how to enlarge the image from the centre (as opposed to from top, left)

Comment: You just need to add `top` and `left` properties to `animate()` similar to `width` and `height`. Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/FZG3v/45/

Comment: If you'll forgive me, one last n00b request.  I have implemented your code on my website, resized the image via CSS, styled the info text and stacked one image over the other to make a second row no problem - it looks awesome!  However, I am having difficulty trying to place the next image in the row.  (4 images each on 2 rows).

Comment: I think the simplest way is to change your `display: block` css property to `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/FZG3v/50/ Good luck :)

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thanks ghost for all your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: I updated a fiddle to solve issues of overlapping images on top of each other.  Since they had the same z-index the 2nd image showed on top - http://jsfiddle.net/FZG3v/65/